# How to send a NULL argument through a DirectFunctionCall?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, apache-age

I'm modifying the function `Datum create_vlabel(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)`, within Apache AGE.

But sometimes it's needed that one of the arguments to this function be `NULL`, and there's a check to that, like this:

```
if (!PG_ARGISNULL(2)) { ... }
```

The thing is, other functions need to call `create_vlabel` with the `DirectFunctionCall` command, but I can't figure out how to pass a `NULL` value through this command.

Everything I tried either broke the system or was not recognized as a proper `NULL` by the `if` clause mentioned above.

Here's everything I tried that did not work:

```
DirectFunctionCall1(create_vlabel, NULL) 
DirectFunctionCall1(create_vlabel, CStringGetDatum("NULL"))
DirectFunctionCall1(create_vlabel, CStringGetDatum(""))
DirectFunctionCall1(create_vlabel, CStringGetDatum(NULL))
DirectFunctionCall1(create_vlabel, PointerGetDatum(NULL))
```

So is there a proper way of sending a `NULL` argument through a `DirectFunctionCall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments in `src/include/fmgr.h` are quite clear on this topic:

```c
/* These are for invocation of a specifically named function with a
 * directly-computed parameter list.  Note that neither arguments nor result
 * are allowed to be NULL.  Also, the function cannot be one that needs to
 * look at FmgrInfo, since there won't be any.
 */
extern Datum DirectFunctionCall1Coll(PGFunction func, Oid collation,
                                     Datum arg1);

[...]

#define DirectFunctionCall1(func, arg1) \
    DirectFunctionCall1Coll(func, InvalidOid, arg1)
```

If you need to call an SQL function will NULL values, you have to use `FunctionCallInvoke()`. Look at `src/backend/tcop/fastpath.c` for inspiration:

- define `fcinfo` with

  ```c
  LOCAL_FCINFO(fcinfo, FUNC_MAX_ARGS);
  ```
- initialize it with `InitFunctionCallInfoData()`
- set `fcinfo->nargs` and `fcinfo->args[i]->isnull` and `fcinfo->args[i]->value` for each argument
- call `FunctionCallInvoke(fcinfo)`

Comment: Hi, there. Sorry. I failed, can you give a full minimum example just like cstring_to_text with cstring as null.

Comment: @jian Too lazy, sorry.